# Is the square of the product of two independent random variables equal to the product of their squares?

Tags: random-variables

Is the square of the product of two independent random variables equal to the product of their squares?

For example: if W = XY, is W^2 = (XY)^2 = (X^2)(Y^2)?

Comment: Random variables are just another word for functions, so given that their image lies in something that is commutative (e.g. $\mathbb Z, \mathbb R, \ldots$), that is the case.

Comment: Context?  Assuming that $X,Y$ are real valued random variables then $XY=YX$ so there is no issue.  But of course, not all random variables are real valued.  If, say, $X,Y$ were matrix valued random variables, then we might not have $XY=YX$.

Comment: Yes, both X and Y are real-valued.